# SetTimeOut on Alert Box

Tags: javascript, alert

Thanks for every bit of help that you have all rendered in this forum.
On behalf of others, I am grateful and want to make you understand that.

Meanwhile, there is this quest that I need to get solved.
Setting a timeout on an alert box.
That is,

```
<?php
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
var t = setTimeOut(5000); //5secs
alert("Your score is: ". $score. '.");
if(t === TRUE){
//clear alert box
this.alert.OK = true;
window.location = "index.php";
}
</script> ';
?>
```

Please do not mind my psudo-code. It's just my wrongest way of understanding javascript to work.

I know that everything is possible - there could be some way of getting around a challenge. But I do not really have the actual solution. And I am throwing it open to the gurus in the house.

Thanks in anticipation that we will all get through this challenge together.
I remain your loyal friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers won't allow timeout on their alert, at-least as of now it is not possible. But here is possible way around. Create a message box with html and css.

*php:*

```
<?
  ... what required to compute/fetch the score
?>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;index.php"/><!-- redirect after 5 secs -->
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="message-box">
    <label>Your score is:<?$score?></label>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The meta tag will tell the browser to redirect to the given page after 5 seconds. Mean while the page is displayed to the user with dynamic score given by the php variable.

**EDIT:** In case if you are not allowed to use meta tags then try this

```
<?
  ... what required to compute/fetch the score
?>
<html>
  <body>
   <div class="message-box">
    <label>Your score is:<?$score?></label>
   </div>
  </body>
  <!-- not a good practice to put tag here, but it will do the trick to redirect after page is loaded-->
  <script>
    setTimeout(function(){
       location.assign("index.php");//<-- where to redirect
    }, 5000); //<-- redirect after 5 secs
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer is good. But getting around it to solve my problem is a challenge.

The scenario is this:
I design a form with radio buttons using php.
When a user clicks on a any radio button, the form gets submitted and the to another page.php which processes the contents of the form.

After the processing, a result is displayed back to the user as an alert and then redirection occurs --> to the previous page

That is, page1.php submits to page2.php which redirects to page1.php.

So, this is where the challenge comes in since all of them are php pages, not using html meta tags.

Comment: @user3134352, please check I have updated my answer.

Comment: Nice one. I will just go with this.

Comment: You can check the entire design using http://eyohonesty.com/school/
... Login using Username & password = "enya11". ...When you are there, click on Write Exam. Try answering any questions... and then you will see the result of your contribution.

Answer (score 2):

You can't time out an alert. It's a low-level JavaScript construct that creates a native application dialog that needs to be confirmed by the user before it gets destroyed. If you want to "throw up data" to the user, you'll have to use an actual HTML dialog library (or roll your own).

Also, don't use `alert()`. It was great when we had no alternative, but these days you use `console.log(...)` to simply log data (any data. numbers and strings, but also entire objects and HTML elements!) to the dev tools console (every browser comes with one baked in), and there are a million and one JS libraries that will generate nice looking modals for users instead (the only legitimate use of an alert these days is to force a halt on the entire page processing thread... And off the top of my head I can't think of a single reason why you'd want to do that).

That said, the PHP code you gave makes absolute no sense at all. It's literally a .js file, with a .php extension. Remove those php tags, save it as .js, and just `<script src="thatfile.js"></script>` that thing. Don't make PHP do things that you don't need PHP for in the slightest.

Comment: Pomax, I really appreciate your suggestive contribution. At least, you have taught me a new thing... console.log in HTML. I must admit that I never knew it. Thank you all the same. God bless you! You are a nice guy.

Answer (score 0):

is it not possible to do:

```
var t = setTimeOut(function(){
alert("Your score is: ". $score. '.");
},5000); //5secs
```

?

Comment: Dear Lucas, nothing in this life is ever impossible! There are so many ways to kill a rat... if you can trap it in one way, you can trap it another way.... whichever way, there is a trapped rat which is the result of the challenge. I really appreciate your efforts. Thank you!