# After Timeout show message then redirect

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need a javascript code to implement a timeout then show an alert then  redirect to another page..

the code is:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(1);
    include("database.php");
    extract($_POST);
    extract($_GET);
    extract($_SESSION);

    /*$rs=mysql_query("select * from mst_question where test_id=$tid",$cn) or             die(mysql_error());
    if($_SESSION[qn]>mysql_num_rows($rs))
    {
    unset($_SESSION[qn]);
    exit;
    }*/
    if (isset($subid) && isset($testid)) {
        $_SESSION[sid] = $subid;
        $_SESSION[tid] = $testid;
        $sqlq          = "SELECT * FROM mst_result WHERE login='$login' and test_id='$testid'";
        $er            = mysqli_query($cn, $sqlq);
        $rc            = mysqli_num_rows($er);
        if ($er > 0) {
            echo " You have already given the exam";
            echo " Click <font color='lightgreen'<a href='sublist.php'>Here</a></font> to             return to exam menu";
        } else {
            header("location:quiz.php");
        }

    }
    if (!isset($_SESSION[sid]) || !isset($_SESSION[tid])) {
        header("location: index.php");
    }
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunction() {
                document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
            }
            function mf() {
                myVar = setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
            }
        </script>
        <title>Online Quiz</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <link href="quiz.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body background="css/bvc.jpg" onload="mf()">
        <?php
            include("header.php");
            echo $time;


            $query="select * from mst_question";

            $rs=mysql_query("select * from mst_question where test_id=$tid",$cn) or     die(mysql_error());
            if(!isset($_SESSION[qn]))
            {
            $_SESSION[qn]=0;
            mysql_query("delete from mst_useranswer where sess_id='" . session_id()     ."'") or die(mysql_error());
                $_SESSION[trueans]=0;

            }
            else
            {   
                if($submit=='Next Question' && isset($ans))
                {
                        mysql_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
                        $row= mysql_fetch_row($rs); 
                        mysql_query("insert into mst_useranswer(sess_id, test_id,     que_des, ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,true_ans,your_ans) values ('".session_id()."',     $tid,'$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]', '$row[6]','$row[7]','$ans')") or     die(mysql_error());
                        if($ans==$row[7])
                        {
                                    $_SESSION[trueans]=$_SESSION[trueans]+1;
                        }
                        $_SESSION[qn]=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
                }
                else if($submit=='Get Result' && isset($ans))
                {
                        mysql_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
                        $row= mysql_fetch_row($rs); 
                        mysql_query("insert into mst_useranswer(sess_id, test_id, que_des, ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,true_ans,your_ans) values ('".session_id()."', $tid,'$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]', '$row[6]','$row[7]','$ans')") or die(mysql_error());
                        if($ans==$row[7])
                        {
                                    $_SESSION[trueans]=$_SESSION[trueans]+1;
                        }
                        echo "<h1 class=head1> Result</h1>";
                        $_SESSION[qn]=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
                        echo "<Table align=center><tr class=tot><td>Total Question<td> $_SESSION[qn]";
                        echo "<tr class=tans><td>True Answer<td>".$_SESSION[trueans];
                        $w=$_SESSION[qn]-$_SESSION[trueans];
                        echo "<tr class=fans><td>Wrong Answer<td> ". $w;
                        echo "</table>";
                        mysql_query("insert into mst_result(login,test_id,test_date,score) values('$login',$tid,'".date("d/m/Y")."',$_SESSION[trueans])") or die(mysql_error());
                        echo "<h1 align=center><a href=review.php> Review Question</a> 
            </h1>";
                        unset($_SESSION[qn]);
                        unset($_SESSION[sid]);
                        unset($_SESSION[tid]);
                        unset($_SESSION[trueans]);
                        exit;
                }
            }
            $rs=mysql_query("select * from mst_question where test_id=$tid",$cn) or         die(mysql_error());
            if($_SESSION[qn]>mysql_num_rows($rs)-1)
            {
            unset($_SESSION[qn]);
            echo "<h1 class=head1>Some Error  Occured</h1>";
            session_destroy();
            echo "Please <a href=index.php> Start Again</a>";

            exit;
            }
            mysql_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
            $row= mysql_fetch_row($rs);
            echo "<form id=myForm method=post action=quiz.php>";
            echo "<table width=100%> <tr> <td width=30>&nbsp;<td> <table border=0>";
            $n=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
            echo "<tR><td><span class=style2>Que ".  $n .": $row[2]</style>";
            echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name=ans value=1>$row[3]";
            echo "<tr><td class=style8> <input type=radio name=ans value=2>$row[4]";
            echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name=ans value=3>$row[5]";
            echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name=ans value=4>$row[6]";

            if($_SESSION[qn]<mysql_num_rows($rs)-1)
            echo "<tr><td><input type=submit name=submit value='Next Question'></form>";
            else
            echo "<tr><td><input type=submit id='t1' name=submit value='Get Result'>        </form>";
            echo "</table></table>";
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

> I am Stuck in the js function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}

function mf()
{
    myVar = setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: please format the code properly and show the code where you are stuck, rather than posting whole bunch of unnecessary code

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** _mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are **wide open to** [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SetTimeOut on Alert Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298824/settimeout-on-alert-box)

Comment: Why are you waiting 3 seconds to submit the form - what's the point of that?

Answer (score 0):

Probably looking into the code I have found that after submitting the form you have to wait for X time and then redirect it.

I give you a suggestion to use ajax instead. Never mind. This can be a solution to your needs

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    //after submitting the form
}
function mf() {
    myVar = setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
    alert('submitted');
    window.location = url;
    //where url can be your any url you wanted to redirect.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should do what you asked for if I understand your question correctly. This function allows you to pass in parameters making it more dynamic and reusable throughout your code (if you needed this functionality multiple places). It's pretty straightforward and has comments.

```
function alertAndRedirectAfterTimeout(timeoutDuration, alertMsgText, redirectUrl) {
    setTimeout(function() { /*setTimeout is a "built-in" js function that will call a callback  function ONE TIME after a specified duration (in milliseconds)*/
        alert(alertMsgText); /*another "built-in" js function that will show an alert on screen*/
        window.location.replace('https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp'); /*this is one way to re-direct the browser window to a url*/
    }, timeoutDuration);
}

/*call the function - you could use this as an event handling function for example when the user clicks on a submit button*/
alertAndRedirectAfterTimeout(2500, 'Redirecting to W3 Schools after 2.5 seconds!', 'https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp');
```